# Export DB using MySQL Console error in syntax

Tags: mysql, export, wamp

I'm using WAMP Server in a local PC.
I'm trying to export a big database using MySQL console but its just not working. I always get a syntax error 1064

The queries I tried:

```
mysqldump -u USER -p DATABASE > backup.sql;
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE > backup.sql;
```

(of course I'm replacing USER, PASSWORD and DATABASE with real values)

I also tried some more similar queries but I'm getting the same syntax error every time.

Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should type this in your command prompt not in MySQL console.

mysqldump is an application not MySQL command.